# Cn1 virtual keyboard ios "done" button and toolbar dissappears.

Tags: ios, keyboard, codenameone

I have a multiline text area at the bottom of the screen. When pressed, the virtual keyboard opens. How do I remove the "done" button at the top right of the keyboard on ios and when the keyboard opens, the entire layout shifts up making the toolbar dissappear, how do I stop this. I tried changing the ios.keyboardOpen flag to both true and false and nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hint `iosHideToolbar` by doing this to your text field:

```
myTextField.putClientProperty("iosHideToolbar", Boolean.TRUE);
```